# Non zero solutions for $y''+(1+x)y=ay,0<x<1,y(0)=y(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For which $a$ does the differential equation $$y''+(1+x)y=ay,0<x<1,y(0)=y(1)=0$$ have a non  zero solution?

Comment: For the eigenvalues of this [Sturm-Liouville-eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory). What are your ideas, what do you know about this type of problems? What type of solution is expected? Theoretical estimates with bounds, numerical approximations,...?

Comment: I just want to know how quickly can I find the range of a to have the solution of that d e because in books couldn't find any theorem regarding this

Comment: Actually I am searching for conditions under which d e y"+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0,y(a)=l,y(b)=m has unique solution,infinitely many solution,no solution.But failed.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Plotting $y(1)$ (for initial values $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$) in dependence of $a$ gives the following picture:

[image]

From the table underlying the graph one finds suitable $a$ close to $-8.375$, $-37.981$, $-87.328$, $-156.41$, $-245.24$.

Try to argue why there are no solutions for $a>2$.

For large negative $a$ the $x$ is a small perturbations to $(-a+1)$ in 
$$
y''+(-a+1+x)y=0.
$$ 
Disregarding $x-0.5$ gives the standard harmonic oscillator $$y''+\omega^2y=0$$ with solutions satisfying the boundary conditions $$y(x)=\sin(n\pi x),$$
which means that $-a+1.5\approx\omega^2= (n\pi)^2$. The first values are
\begin{array}{l|l}n&a\approx1.5-(n\pi)^2\\\hline
1 & -8.36960440109 \\
2 & -37.9784176044 \\
3 & -87.3264396098 \\
4 & -156.413670417 \\
5 & -245.240110027 \\
6 & -353.805758439 \\
7 & -482.110615653 \\
8 & -630.15468167 \\
9 & -797.937956488 \\
\end{array}
which is close enough to the numerical results for a first approximation.